# Restarting a PHP Loop

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, reset

I have this piece of code

```
foreach($mnthArrPtrn as $m => $mn)
{   
    if(!isset($catName)) {
        $catVals = array();      
        $prevCat = $catName = $pntChrtQry[0]['CAT']['categoryname']; 
        $pntVals .= '{name:'.$catName.',data:[';
    }else if($prevCat != $catName) {
        $prevCat = $catName;
        $catVals = array(); 
        $pntVals .= '{name:'.$catName.',data:[';
    }     
    foreach($pntChrtQry as $key => $val){
        $catName = $val['CAT']['categoryname'];
        if($prevCat != $catName){
            continue 2;
        }
        echo '<br />$m::'.$m; 
        echo '<br />$mn::'.$mn;
        echo '<br />$val::'.$val[0]['MNTH'];
        if($m == $val[0]['MNTH'] || $mn == $val[0]['MNTH']){
            $catVals[] = $val[0]['total'];
        }
    }
    pr($catVals);
    if(!isset($catName)){
        $pntVals .= ']},';
    }
    $catName = $val['CAT']['categoryname'];
}
```

1st loop iterates over a months array which are joined as a key value pair.
What I am doing here is on getting a new catName I continue the internal loop but at the same time I want to restart loop 1 with $prevCat,$catName still preserving their values.
Is this possible? Sorry If this is a silly question.

I tried converting the first one to a while statement and use a reset then but It didn't help me.

Comment: a) give your variables, good names like $month, $months, $category, $values, etc. b) Break this up into multiple clear functions, this code drives one crazy to read. c) If you want to convert a PHP array to a JSON array, use the native functions for that.

Comment: Isnt there a way to reset the extrnl loop?

Comment: If you need to restart a loop, use `while` in conjunction with `each`, with a `reset` to go back to the start of an array. You can't restart a `foreach`, no.

Comment: is that possible to do right above the continue statement?I want to restart the extrnl one

Comment: This is really not good code, so it's worth refactoring it anyways. You can probably solve it by introducing yet more cryptical and unreadable stuff but then it will just be unmaintainable code. So go the refactoring way and break it down into a couple of dedicated functions.

Comment: @markus-tharkun How did you expected this to be

Comment: @techie_28 What did you mean with that last comment?

Comment: @markus-tharkun I have a situation where I need to form a json string to feed to some charts which has divisions of 2 consecutive months an year and I was getting them from Database and this is was the way I thought it should be.I really dont know if there is better way todo so

Comment: If you're creating JSON strings, use `json_encode` - unless there's a reason you cannot.

Comment: Yes but I have to formulate the array like that also.

Comment: _I have to formulate the array like that also_ - what do you mean by that? The `json_encode` function can encode arrays just fine.

Comment: @techie_28 form the required array in PHP first, then use json_encode. (and keep working on improving your english, it will help you greatly!)

Comment: Thnx @markus eventually I sorted it out like you have said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this will allow you to arbitrarily restart a loop:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($mnthArrPtrn)) {
    if ($needToRestart) {
        reset($mnthArrPtrn);
    }
}
```

See more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php).

Comment: I have a nested loop inside the external one..And on that continue I want to restart...will that work/

Comment: Yes, I think so. Swap the outer loop for the one I suggest, and `reset` the array before you do `continue 2`.

Comment: Perhaps your `continue` should be at the end of your inner loop? I don't know, since I don't know the algorithm, nor the purpose of the code.

Comment: That didnt helped too @halfer I tried the outer foreach to be while(list($m,$mn) = each($mnthArrPtrn))

Comment: Well, this is where you have to do some debugging. It's probably worth my pointing out that (in general) if you respond with "That didn't help too", there's not much I can say unless you can explain _in detail_ how it didn't help. Otherwise I have to guess, which isn't very useful! `:)`

Comment: Try entering a test string, and then use `echo/exit` at various points to see if the intermediate results are as you would expect. Do this iteratively until fixed. In other words, break your large problem into small problems that are trivially fixable, and test each bit.

Comment: Dont know what the problem with my side is.But I have found this to be the solution to restart a while loop.Thnx @halfer..Thnx all.